# How to avoid hangings when scraping JSON formatted data from API URL using Python

Tags: python, freeze

I've been parsing the data (keys and values) from JSON formatted API URL using Python. My code has been running without any problem for three weeks. But since three days ago, Python suddenly fails to run my code and doesn't collect the data to the end.

The weird thing is that terminal doesn't show any error or doesn't automatically stops running, but it just hangs there and doesn't move on (as if it it were trapped in a infinite loop). To be simple, I'm using a `for` loop to iterate through all the elements (product IDs) in a list and try to get the corresponding keys and values.

When Python hangs, there's no particular pattern. I googled and added this on my code:

```
for i in product_list:
     try:
         # Collecting the data
     except:
         pass
     else:
         continue
```

After adding this code, Python goes a way further (collecting more data before it hangs again) than before, but it still hangs at a random point. Is there a way to avoid this type of issue? I tried to describe my issue as much as possible but this time I can't even find out what the error is.

Comment: is `product_list` well formatted json? are you logging exceptions inside `except`? why use `else continue block`?

Comment: @PruthviKumar Yes. For every product ID, the structure is the same.

Comment: P.S. I use windows 7 & I tried interruptingcow python module but it doesn't work. The error message said there's no attribute for signal, SIGARLM.

Comment: @PruthviKumar I used else continue block since I thought it makes skip any error and moves on to the next iteration (sorry I'm not an expert at programming).